# Instance member cannot be used on type?

Tags: swift

I have the following class:

```
struct Console {
    static let formatter = DateFormatter()
    fileprivate var logger: ((_: String) -> Void)?

    public static func log(_ level: Slog_ClientLog.LogLevel,_ tag: String,_ message: String) {
        #if DEBUG
        if logger == nil {
            var output = ""
            switch level {
            case .verbose: output += " VERBOSE"
            case .debug: output += " DEBUG"
            case .info: output += " INFO"
            case .warning: output += " WARNING"
            case .error: output += " ERROR"
            default: output += ""
            }
            if tag.count != 0 {
                output += " [\(tag)] "
            }
            let time = formatter.string(from: Date())
            output += "\(time):"
            if message.count != 0 {
                output += message
            }
            print(output)
        } else {
            logger!(message)
        }
        #endif
    }
    
    public static func setPrivateLogger(imp: ((_: String) -> Void)?) {
        logger = imp
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with the message:

`Instance member 'logger' cannot be used on type 'Console'`

What does this mean?

If I put the logger outside the Console,it's ok.

Comment: Unrelated but the syntax `(_: String)` is legacy Swift 2 code. Just write `(String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be;

```
public mutating func setPrivateLogger(imp: ((_: String) -> Void)?) {
    logger = imp
}
```

explanation:
struct is a value type. Therefore, when you change it, you actually get a new value just like Int, String or another value type.
Because it is a value type, you cannot change it in its own instance.
"By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods" (Swift documentation)
To be able to do this, you need "mutating" behavior.

- for more info:
  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html

if you want to set "logger" only in Struct, you can define it as "private(set) var logger" or if you want to access it only in Struct, you can define it as "private var logger"

```
struct Console {
static let formatter = DateFormatter()
private(set) var logger: ((_: String) -> Void)?

public static func log(_ level: Slog_ClientLog.LogLevel,_ tag: String,_ message: String) {
    // other code
 }

public mutating func setPrivateLogger(imp: ((_: String) -> Void)?) {
    logger = imp
 }
}
```

Comment: the problem is not about fileprivate, it is about "static" func. you should replace "static" with "mutating"

Comment: also, are you sure that you want to make it "fileprivate" but not "private"?

Comment: ,if i make it public instead of fileprivate,it's ok.

Comment: you can also make it "private"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: more explanation is added @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an instance variable in a typed function (static function here, same error would appear if it was a class function). Had it been an instance method or your var had been a static property you would not get this error.

Have a look at the two vars in the console class, formatter is a static property(Console.formatter) while logger is an instance property(will be accessed by instances of Console, i.e Console().formatter).

You need to review the Console class design and figure out what you do you need.

See if you can keep logger as static var.

For the 2nd point, When you declare it outside the class its a regular variable of type ((_: String) -> Void)? and is no longer an attribute class Console.